# MySQLDump batch file is empty while the power shell version has content

Tags: powershell, batch-file, mysql

I would like to use windows task scheduler to backup tables from a MySQL database every night. I created a .bat file that runs via the task scheduler. It creates the file but the file is empty. Here is the code:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe"   --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --user=root --password=password --set-gtid-purged=OFF --flush-privileges=TRUE --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "maintenance" "safe_main" > "D:\testDump2.sql"
```

This will create the file and name it appropriately but the file is empty. This happens even when I run the bat file as an admin.

However when I run the same line in Windows Powershell it will create the same file with content.

The end result needs to be an sql file with data every night. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems the obvious response is 'Why don't you use PowerShell and not a batch file in your scheduled task?'

Comment: I acknowledge that because the power shell works then I should try to use the power shell script instead of the batch file. However, various dynamics beyond the scope of this issue suggest that the batch solution would be more appropriate.

Comment: If you don't use redirection to a file, do you have any command output on screen?

Comment: Hmm. What is redirection to a file? The file is being created but its empty. As for command output to the screen. I want to say no because I'm not clear about what that would look like.

Comment: Read more about [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). If your command can't output the result to screen without using `>` sign, it would explain something wrong is with this command, or the output format is not supported by Cmd interpreter. Try `START "" /b /w /d "path" "your_program.exe" --"options"` and watch on screen output.